# MYSQL cuts off part of a string on GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, database, text

I'm using this command to create whole table:

```
INSERT INTO `odm_rodzice`(`Kropkoogonek`, `Rodzice`, `RodziceID`, `Ilosc`) 
SELECT 
    Kropkoogonek, 
    group_concat(`Slowo` separator ', ') AS Rodzice, 
    group_concat(`Rodzic` separator ', ') AS RodziceID,
    COUNT(*) AS Liczba
FROM odm_kropkoogonki 
LEFT JOIN odm_slownik ON odm_kropkoogonki.Rodzic = odm_slownik.ID
WHERE odm_kropkoogonki.ID = 2000000
GROUP BY Kropkoogonek
```

It turned out that longest resulting string (260 6-letter words) is too short and somehow cutted:

```
SELECT Rodzice FROM slownik.`odm_rodzice` WHERE Kropkoogonek = 'p.....'; 

GIVES:

płonne, poznał, polazę, (...) pszona, pełzną, pełzną, pełz
```

It has 893 letters - while it shoud have about 1838 (including ', ') and last word is incomplete.

Column type is TEXT.

What am i doing wrong?

Best regards!

Comment: You've tagged this with phpmyadmin. Why?

Comment: yeah, i didn't mention that i execute command via phpmyadmi, but was almost sure it is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being affected by `group_concat_max_len` (documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)).

The maximum value is 1024 *bytes*.  You have accented characters, so your average character length is probably a bit more than one byte.

You can change this value to a larger value and re-run the query.